# Spring oauth2 save client in database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hello how can i save client that authenticate with google, in database?
I have tried do it this way: http://mmkay.pl/2017/03/19/spring-boot-saving-oauth2-login-data-in-db-using-principalextractor
But PrincipalExecutor didnt execute anytime..
Cookie is being set, everything works as it should, but i dont know how to implement user saving...

Security config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/non-secured").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .permitAll();
    }


}
```

properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=******************************.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=****************************
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```